# Launch multiple modeless C#.Net forms from Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am working on a feature for our Excel based app. For simplicity sake, say, Excel cells have positive integers. We want to popup C#.Net modeless form if the cell data is integer else don’t.
User clicks on a cell, that triggers Excel_SheetSelectionChange event. After validation of data, we go to C#. If there is a form open previously, it’s closed and a new form replaces it. The forms come with a ‘Don’t close’ button. If user chooses to press ‘Don’t close’ button the new form doesn’t close the previous form. Upto a maximum of 5 such windows can be kept opened. If it’s >5, next form doesn’t show ‘Don’t close’ button until one of the previous forms is closed.

I am not able to crack the logic of doing **without using timers**.

```
    …
     mCount = Application.OpenForms.Count;
     if (mCount > 5)
     {
        dontCloseButton.Enabled = false;
     }

     SetLocation();
     SetTimer();
  } 

  private void SetTimer()
  {
     Timer.Interval = 200;
     Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerElapsed);
     Timer.Start();
  }

  void TimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Excel.Range range = xlcell.Application.ActiveCell;
     if (range.AddressLocal.ToString() == xlcell.AddressLocal.ToString())
     {
        Timer.Stop();
        Timer.Start();
     }
     else
     {
        Timer.Stop();
        Close();
     }
  }

  private void EvenIntForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
  {
     this.Dispose();
  }
```

**EDIT-1:** Since there is no answer yet, let me ask, how can Timer event handler be avoided from my code? Any suggestions?

```
 Private Sub mExcel_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal theSheet As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
'Sample code
If (ActiveSheet.Type = -4167) And CheckIsNumber (Target.Application.ActiveCell) Then
    LoadPopForm Target.Application.ActiveCell
End If
```

Comment: What's a ".Net form"?

Comment: Can you show the `Excel_SheetSelectionChange event`?

Comment: .Net form as in Winform. @Idle_Mind, i have added event code in the query body

Comment: It just seems like you should be able to repeatedly call `LoadPopForm`, passing in that cell,  and have it determine if the  form should be opened, left as is, or closed.  You'd have to use some kind of Dictionary with the cell as the key, and the modeless form as the value to track the forms and retrieve them.